# Can't select data when adding a binding from a prompt to selected range on Office online

Tags: excel, office-js

I want to select a range with the binding from a prompt. To implement this I follow the spec: [Add a binding from a prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/bind-to-regions-in-a-document-or-spreadsheet#add-a-binding-from-a-prompt)

The behavior is ok on Excel desktop but on Excel online I can't select a range with the mouse.

I reproduce this in the Script Lab tool and I have export a gist. The gist is available on: [Get data binding from a prompt.EXCEL.yaml](https://gist.github.com/Nassim33/4131bf1e73ca92663481a6e828035eef#file-get-data-binding-from-a-prompt-excel-yaml)

For testing,

1. Open a document on Office online
2. Launch ScriptLab and open the project
3. Click on "Set binding on data" button to open the prompt (to create a binding on the cells to get their values)
4. Try to select a range with the mouse

Is this behavior on Excel online normal ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for now, that is the current behavior. We don't have great 'range picker' support for Excel for web, which just defaults to asking users to manually type in the address. It is something we're considering on improving on with new controls and APIs in the future.

To stay up to date, I'd suggest logging this on UserVoice and we can update it when we start: https://officespdev.uservoice.com.

thanks!

Comment: Hi @Keyur , I have logging this lack on UserVoice https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/42775244-set-the-behavior-of-range-picker-in-excel-online.